# best MVC framework for Adobe Flex

Tags: apache-flex, adobe, cairngorm, robotlegs

I need to develop a web conferencing app in Adobe flex, was actually confuse about the MVC framework I can use I have done a some research and found two main contenders 
1- Robot Legs 
2- Cairngorm 
Can anyone tell which one to use one of these two or any other?

Comment: IMO Flex _is_ an MVC framework (and a pretty good one if we're talking Flex 4) and doesn't need any third-party tools to bloat the application and make it more complex than it should be. The only thing lacking in the toolset (from my point of view that is) is an IoC container and I have yet to find a framework that only takes care of the IoC part.

Comment: How comes you didnot found `Mate` as contender ?

Comment: Didn't check mate will check it definitely, but like your idea to use Flex as an MVC, any ideas about its MVC architecture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cairngorm has been around the longest, and it probably has the [most developers](http://blog.flexdevelopers.com/2011/08/finding-most-popular-flex-framework.html), Adobe's latest move on Cairngorm is largely building libraries instead of extending the framework.  I have heard some architectures complain that Cairngorm uses singleton Model, and a better practice should be utilizing IoC (Inversion of Control) and DI (Dependency-Injection).  If any of these make sense to you, go for Robot Legs or Parsley.  The latter two are newer and more modern.  But be prepared that learning curve for Robot Legs and Parsley could be steeper for some.

If not, Cairngorm is not bad, the architecture itself is very light and small, and there are numerous books and discussions you can mine through.  After all, "best" is a subjective word here.  It is more about getting your work done in a timely manner.

Comment: Even though I despise the Cairngorm framework, +1 for citing sources that it has the most developers.

Comment: I think Robot legs is the one with less boiler plate code. I used cairngorn, pureMVC and RobotLegs I stick with the last.

Comment: All Flex frameworks are in fact pretty young and immature and Cairngorm is definitely the worst of them all (I have to disagree with the `Cairngorm is not bad` statement). It has the merit of being the first, which is why many design mistakes were made (from which other frameworks learned), and why it has the most developers. I know we've had a similar argument before, but I actually think that learning IoC (1 concept) is easier than learning about all those classes you have to extend in Cairngorm (many concepts).

Comment: I have to agree with RIAStar on this. Cairngorm is by far the worst flex framework I have ever used. It promotes numerous bindings and will force you to couple components to the framework itself. Whereas other frameworks like robotlegs or swiz are less intrusive.

Comment: wow, you guys are fast, like the answers, I will go with RIAStar too and use Flex , Cairngorm is complex and Robot Legs is good but will add much time to development. Thanks Guys

Comment: I have used RobotLegs and PureMVC and found them to be invaluable in very large projects. I prefer RobotLegs - more intuitive, less boilerplate code